# Custom Spree Discounts. Points system for discount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, spree, payment-processing

I don't have tons of experience in ruby nor Spree, but I have been playing around with the Spree 3.0 stable version for a while and I was wondering about how can I implement a discount system based in points which users collect somehow.

According to that, a user could select the amount of points that he wants to use for a determinate product in the product details page, lets say next to the "add to cart" button. Each point has a representation in the current currency, so right after the item has been added to the cart, I want to calculate the discount based in the selected quantity of points and attach it to the current order.

I have been try to set some values in @order to try to receive the correct amount (I mean, the discount amount not included) in my spree payment gateway (which is stripe) without success.

I have tried to change from a view using ruby code:

```
@order.item_total
@order.total
@order.promo_total
@order.amount (this is not even possible to set like I am trying to do it)
```

The thing is that Stripe always get the payment for the complete amount, not including the discount.

What and where should I change to modify the amount that the Spree payment gateway receive? Doesn't the payment gateway receive the complete order object?

I would appreciate any help to clear this, also if you have any idea about how to get my goal it also would be appreciated.